# Getting uknown error when using mupdf

Tags: android, error-handling, mupdf

I've tried to import mupdf to my app, but when I open it, i got some weird error and it force closes. Why? I really don't understand.

this is my logcat:

```
10-10 15:34:17.802    8657-8657/com.tproductions.Openit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tproductions.Openit, PID: 8657
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.openFile:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.openFile(Native Method)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<init>(MuPDFCore.java:68)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:204)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:303)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you may have not build your native code the right way. Have you check all the steps with NDK and all?

Comment: Yup, I tried to do it with ndk but failed. So I just copied and pasted it. I couldn't find the good tutorial for newbies. Maybe that's the case

Comment: The latest version of NDK seems to have issues. Use NDK 8re, for example. Follow the steps in http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something has gone wrong in the native build.

It's probably best to retry that; there are instructions here:

http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

and here:

http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob_plain;f=platform/android/ReadMe.txt;hb=HEAD

It's probably best to use the git code from master - the latest is 1.6, versions prior to 1.5 are unlikely to build cleanly with the current NDKs.

Comment: Well, If I read rheir instructions I really don't understand it. I don't know how to use command line and all the things. So, I just deleted the code